# Can Amazon Sumerian react to events from Amazon SNS, or is IoT my only route?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sumerian

I'm new to Sumerian but I've been able to create a demo scene. I'd like to have the scene respond to external events, ideally published through SNS.

Is it possible to do this directly with a script or is the only route to create an IoT shadow and process events that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Sumerian runs in your web browser. You can extend a scene by writing JavaScript. For example, the JavaScript could call out to AWS or other web services.

Sumerian will not "react" to external events, but you can **use JavaScript and libraries to call other services** (eg AWS IoT) on a regular basis to poll for information. The result can be that a Sumerian scene appears to 'react', but it's really just regularly checking an external source.

So, as long as you can call an API to obtain some data, you can make it look like Sumerian is responding to external triggers.

Examples:

- [IoT Thing, Shadow, and Script Actions | Learn Amazon Sumerian](https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/tutorials/create/intermediate/iot-thing-shadow-script/)
- [How to Communicate with Amazon Sumerian via AWS IoT](https://medium.com/@samrastovich/how-to-communicate-with-amazon-sumerian-via-aws-iot-c89b3a25fd)